# openOCD not working?

Tags: stm32, embedded, iot

I am trying to use Zephyr RTOS with my board B_L4S5I_IOT01A. After following the getting started guide, I can't flash the .hex file into my board.
This is what the terminal looks like after I tried to 'west flash'.
[image]

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is that I want to flash the basic 'Hello_World' .hex file and then get a response back and showed onto the terminal.
Is there anything I can do?
Change the openOCD flasher into another one?
Is there any way I can just use the terminal without the help of any software?

Thank you!

Comment: please remove the screenshots and add the actual text

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! May I know which Stack Exchange it should be placed? I will move the question there!

Comment: You did not say anything about your setup. From screenshot it look that you are running openocd in some VM. What VM is it? VMWare, VirtualBox, KVM, Hyper-V? Does it work if you run openocd directly on cumputer with attached devboard? Do it work with STM32CubdeIDE or other ST tools?